# Woocommerce change the design of the checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm new to Woocommerce. I want to change the structure of the checkout page. Now I looked into the file "form-checkout". This is the right file?

In this file there is not much of the structure. I find many php actions. For example:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>
```

Where can I see the content of this action? So I can go in that file and change the structure?

P.S. Does anyone want to share more knowledge about Woocommerce with me?

Answer (score 1):

There are several php files that make up the checkout page.

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/

cart-errors.php

form-billing.php

form-checkout.php

form-coupon.php

form-login.php

form-pay.php

form-shipping.php

review-order.php

thankyou.php

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php is the main file.

It's recommended that you copy the template folder from the woocommerce plugin directory, put it at the root of your theme and rename it to woocommerce (leaving the template folder intact in the plugin directory to allow for upgrading).

Comment: Yes and in this files actions are called. One action outputs a table with input fields. Now I want to change this table, but I don't know where I can find the function which creates this table.

Comment: Sorry user3285007, The file that is showing the table is class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php